# Python to Python WebSockets with websockets and flask-socketio

Tags: flask, websocket, socket.io, python-3.6

## Problem

So I need to make a python application that can sit on a machine, open up a websocket pipe to a server running flask-socketio, then pipe data across to the server. The data will be json data, for now I am testing with a string.

I am having an issue using the 'websockets' library in python to connect to the 'flask-socketio' backend that I am making.

## Code

### Server

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, 

copy_current_request_context
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import logging

logging.basicConfig()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/')
def connect():
    print('Client connected')


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/')
def disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

### Client 1 - websockets library

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect(
            'ws://127.0.0.1:5000') as websocket:
        name = 'joe'  # input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send('message', name)
        print(f"> {name}")

        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {greeting}")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())

print("end")
```

#### Use output

When I use client 1 I get this as output on the client process:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/project_files/aWebUAS/micro-services/New-Capabilities-Investigation/web_socket_client.py", line 15, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:/project_files/aWebUAS/micro-services/New-Capabilities-Investigation/web_socket_client.py", line 6, in hello
    'ws://127.0.0.1:5000') as websocket:
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\py35\client.py", line 2, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\py35\client.py", line 20, in __await_impl__
    extra_headers=protocol.extra_headers,
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 286, in handshake
    raise InvalidStatusCode(status_code)
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: Status code not 101: 404`

and on the flask process I see:
`127.0.0.1 - - [2019-04-05 09:17:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.000999`

### Client 2 - websocket-client library

```
import websocket
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:5000")
ws.send("Hello, World")
```

#### Use output

On the client 2 process I get this as output:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/project_files/aWebUAS/micro-services/New-Capabilities-Investigation/web_socket_client_2.py", line 3, in <module>
    ws.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:5000")
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 226, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 79, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.py", line 160, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d %s", status, status_message, resp_headers)
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 404 NOT FOUND`

and the flask process shows this:
`127.0.0.1 - - [2019-04-05 09:11:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 342 0.001000`

## Conclusion

Some reading around tells me I am not hitting my socketio handler within flask properly, but I am unsure how to target that.

Any help is much appreciated. My goal is to have a python script talking to a flask socketio server. I am not married to any part of this but would prefer to stick to flask for the server.

TIA - Ian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have figured this out by now, but the issue is likely the fact that flask-socketio is a Socket.IO implementation, not a websocket implementation. Socket.IO uses websockets as one of its communication protocols, but you will need a Socket.IO client to connect to the flask-socketio server.

See [socketio's docs](https://socket.io/docs/#What-Socket-IO-is-not), specifically:

> Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed
>   uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds some metadata to
>   each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the ack id when a
>   message acknowledgement is needed. That is why a WebSocket client will
>   not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a
>   Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a WebSocket server
>   either.

Take a look at this python Socket.IO client.
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio